# Getting "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError" when trying to include Twilio API in android app

Tags: android, twilio

I am trying to include Twilio API in my android app, But when I try to send sms from it, I am getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError. I tried to resolve it by adding httpclient-4.2.2.jar file , but no success.

**Below is my Error Log:**

```
12-06 10:32:26.497: E/AndroidRuntime(12901): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-06 10:32:26.497: E/AndroidRuntime(12901): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager.<init>
12-06 10:32:26.497: E/AndroidRuntime(12901):    at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient.<init>(TwilioRestClient.java:137)
12-06 10:32:26.497: E/AndroidRuntime(12901):    at com.example.twiliodemo.TwilioDemo.sendMessageByTwilio(TwilioDemo.java:40)
12-06 10:32:26.497: E/AndroidRuntime(12901):    at com.example.twiliodemo.TwilioDemo.onCreate(TwilioDemo.java:23)
12-06 10:32:26.497: E/AndroidRuntime(12901):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
12-06 10:32:26.497: E/AndroidRuntime(12901):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
12-06 10:32:26.497: E/AndroidRuntime(12901):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
12-06 10:32:26.497: E/AndroidRuntime(12901):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
12-06 10:32:26.497: E/AndroidRuntime(12901):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
12-06 10:32:26.497: E/AndroidRuntime(12901):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
12-06 10:32:26.497: E/AndroidRuntime(12901):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-06 10:32:26.497: E/AndroidRuntime(12901):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-06 10:32:26.497: E/AndroidRuntime(12901):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-06 10:32:26.497: E/AndroidRuntime(12901):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 10:32:26.497: E/AndroidRuntime(12901):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-06 10:32:26.497: E/AndroidRuntime(12901):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-06 10:32:26.497: E/AndroidRuntime(12901):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-06 10:32:26.497: E/AndroidRuntime(12901):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**This is my activity.**

```
package com.example.twiliodemo;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.factory.SmsFactory;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.instance.Account;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.instance.Sms;

public class TwilioDemo extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        sendMessageByTwilio();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void sendMessageByTwilio(){
         /* Find your sid and token at twilio.com/user/account */
        try {
            String ACCOUNT_SID = "AC15b63878d56d436af26cfd6f0e94c706";
            String AUTH_TOKEN = "2c870b5aa3c5f4d1bcacbe747d6808f6";
            String TWILIO_URL="http://api.twilio.com"; 

            TwilioRestClient clientTwilio=new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN,TWILIO_URL);
                Account account = clientTwilio.getAccount();

                SmsFactory smsFactory = account.getSmsFactory();
                Map<String, String> smsParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
                smsParams.put("To", "+919423872793"); 
                smsParams.put("From", "+12403486854"); // Replace with a valid phone
                // number in your account
                smsParams.put("Body", "Hi..");

                Sms sms = smsFactory.create(smsParams);
                Log.d("SMS -", ""+sms);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("**************", String.valueOf(e));
        }
    }

}
```

I have also added 'twilio-java-sdk-3.3.10.jar' in libs folder.

Comment: did you provided the path to the jar in build path?

Comment: @AndroSelva yes I have declared jars in buildpath.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your project and if you have a separate project you use make sure you have set it as a library project!